# What should I do with this question now I've found an answer?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I've just posted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24608757/securityerror-the-operation-is-insecure-when-using-ajaxupload-library), and after some debugging I found an answer on a different question. What should I do with my original question now as it turns out to be a duplicate of another? Should I delete it? Admittedly this could have been avoided if I did some more debugging before posting the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have several options.

- Answer it. Please make sure you answer it fully, and include a link to the question that helped you.
- Vote to close it as a duplicate of the other question.
- Post a comment with a link to the other question, and other people will vote to close it for you.

Comment: Okay I've done this now, cheers.

Answer (score 1):

You have these options:

1. You can mark your question as duplicate and close it.
2. You can self-answer the question by giving proper accreditation.

Comment: For the second option - the OP even should do that, or at least remove the answer part from the question. Posting a solution inside the question is not a good practice.

Comment: I've done both of the above now.